# multiline formatting for verbatim strings in c# (prefix with @)

Tags: c#, .net, string, multiline, verbatim-string

I love using the @"strings" in c#, especially when I have a lot of multi-line text. The only annoyance is that my code formatting goes to doodie when doing this, because the second and greater lines are pushed fully to the left instead of using the indentation of my beautifully formatted code. I know this is by design, but is there some option/hack way of allowing these lines to be indented, without adding the actual tabs/spaces to the output?

adding example:

```
        var MyString = @" this is 
a multi-line string
in c#.";
```

My variable declaration is indented to the "correct" depth, but the second and further lines in the string get pushed to the left margin- so the code is kinda ugly. You could add tabs to the start of line 2 and 3, but the string itself would then contain those tabs... make sense?

Comment: What i normally do is start the string on its own line (i.e. newline before the `@`), so at least it's not on the right then suddenly on the left. I know it's not a solution you're after though.

Comment: Yes I often do that as well. And it's really not a really big deal, but I thought this would be an interesting question to ask.

Comment: The real question should be is it worth extra processing of strings if it makes your source code better looking?

Comment: a compile-time fix would be optimal, but that would be asking a lot ;)

Comment: Well it can be worth it in other cases too if you're logging say a multiline SQL statement.

Comment: When do you ever need this? The only cases in which I’ve ever used multi-line verbatim strings is for strings containing SQL, HTML, CSS, JavaScript or some other code — in all cases, the extra whitespace doesn’t matter and can safely stay in the string.

Comment: I've earned a popular question badge for this one. I'm almost embarrassed by this ;)

Comment: @boomhauer Why embarrassed?  It's not shameful to strive to keep your code clean, easy to read and editable.  I wish more programmers made it a priority in their work.

Comment: I am spoiled by Python's `textwrap.dedent()` function and found this question in my search for a C# equivalent.

Comment: Please see (and upvote) my suggestion for change in the Visual Studio IDE: [Indent multi-line verbatim strings](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/602807/indent-multi-line-verbatim-strings.html).

Answer (score 14):

How about a string extension? Update: I reread your question and I hope there is a better answer. This is something that bugs me too and having to solve it as below is frustrating but on the plus side it does work.

```cs
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public static class StringExtensions
    {
        public static string StripLeadingWhitespace(this string s)
        {
            Regex r = new Regex(@"^\s+", RegexOptions.Multiline);
            return r.Replace(s, string.Empty);
        }
    }
}
```

And an example console program:

```cs
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string x = @"This is a test
                of the emergency
                broadcasting system.";

            Console.WriteLine(x);

            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("---");
            Console.WriteLine();

            Console.WriteLine(x.StripLeadingWhitespace());

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

And the output:

```cs
This is a test
                of the emergency
                broadcasting system.

---

This is a test
of the emergency
broadcasting system.
```

And a cleaner way to use it if you decide to go this route:

```cs
string x = @"This is a test
    of the emergency
    broadcasting system.".StripLeadingWhitespace();
// consider renaming extension to say TrimIndent() or similar if used this way
```

Comment: yeah this is a solution I was thinking of. Might need to add intelligence to strip only a certain number of spaces or tabs, since it IS possible you want a space/tab on some lines ;)

Comment: And maybe check if the string starts with any whitespace and default to replacing `^\s+` with that amount of whitespace if so?

Answer (score 7):

Cymen has given the right solution. I use a similar approach as derived from Scala's stripMargin() method. Here's what my extension method looks like:

```
public static string StripMargin(this string s)
{
    return Regex.Replace(s, @"[ \t]+\|", string.Empty);
}
```

*Usage:*

```
var mystring = @"
        |SELECT 
        |    *
        |FROM
        |    SomeTable
        |WHERE
        |    SomeColumn IS NOT NULL"
    .StripMargin();
```

*Result:*

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    SomeTable
WHERE
    SomeColumn IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 6):

with C# 11 you can now use [raw string literals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-11#raw-string-literals).

```
var MyString = """
    this is 
    a multi-line string
    in c#.
    """;
```

The output is:

```
this is
a multi-line string
in c#.
```

It also combines with string interpolation:

```
var variable = 24.3;
var myString = $"""
    this is 
    a multi-line string
    in c# with a {variable}.
    """;
```

Comment: Pretty great right?

Answer (score 2):

I can't think of an answer that would completely satisfy your question, however you could write a function that strips leading spaces from lines of text contained in a string and call it on each creation of such a string.

```
var myString = TrimLeadingSpacesOfLines(@" this is a 
    a multi-line string
    in c#.");
```

Yes it is a hack, but you specified your acceptance of a hack in your question.

Comment: the catch is- I may want some leading blank spaces in some situations, so I only want enough blank space removed so that the text would hit the left margin... make sense?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a longish solution which tries to mimic `textwrap.dedent` as much as possible. The first line is left as-is and expected not to be indented. (You can generate the unit tests based on the doctests using [doctest-csharp](https://github.com/mristin/doctest-csharp/).)

```
/// <summary>
/// Imitates the Python's
/// <a href="https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html#textwrap.dedent">
/// <c>textwrap.dedent</c></a>.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="text">Text to be dedented</param>
/// <returns>array of dedented lines</returns>
/// <code doctest="true">
/// Assert.That(Dedent(""), Is.EquivalentTo(new[] {""}));
/// Assert.That(Dedent("test me"), Is.EquivalentTo(new[] {"test me"}));
/// Assert.That(Dedent("test\nme"), Is.EquivalentTo(new[] {"test", "me"}));
/// Assert.That(Dedent("test\n  me"), Is.EquivalentTo(new[] {"test", "  me"}));
/// Assert.That(Dedent("test\n  me\n    again"), Is.EquivalentTo(new[] {"test", "me", "  again"}));
/// Assert.That(Dedent("  test\n  me\n    again"), Is.EquivalentTo(new[] {"  test", "me", "  again"}));
/// </code>
private static string[] Dedent(string text)
{
    var lines = text.Split(
        new[] {"\r\n", "\r", "\n"},
        StringSplitOptions.None);

    // Search for the first non-empty line starting from the second line.
    // The first line is not expected to be indented.
    var firstNonemptyLine = -1;
    for (var i = 1; i < lines.Length; i++)
    {
        if (lines[i].Length == 0) continue;

        firstNonemptyLine = i;
        break;
    }

    if (firstNonemptyLine < 0) return lines;

    // Search for the second non-empty line.
    // If there is no second non-empty line, we can return immediately as we
    // can not pin the indent.
    var secondNonemptyLine = -1;
    for (var i = firstNonemptyLine + 1; i < lines.Length; i++)
    {
        if (lines[i].Length == 0) continue;

        secondNonemptyLine = i;
        break;
    }

    if (secondNonemptyLine < 0) return lines;

    // Match the common prefix with at least two non-empty lines
    
    var firstNonemptyLineLength = lines[firstNonemptyLine].Length;
    var prefixLength = 0;
    
    for (int column = 0; column < firstNonemptyLineLength; column++)
    {
        char c = lines[firstNonemptyLine][column];
        if (c != ' ' && c != '\t') break;
        
        bool matched = true;
        for (int lineIdx = firstNonemptyLine + 1; lineIdx < lines.Length; 
                lineIdx++)
        {
            if (lines[lineIdx].Length == 0) continue;
            
            if (lines[lineIdx].Length < column + 1)
            {
                matched = false;
                break;
            }

            if (lines[lineIdx][column] != c)
            {
                matched = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!matched) break;
        
        prefixLength++;
    }

    if (prefixLength == 0) return lines;
    
    for (var i = 1; i < lines.Length; i++)
    {
        if (lines[i].Length > 0) lines[i] = lines[i].Substring(prefixLength);
    }

    return lines;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I wanted the textrwap.dedent behavior where it only strips the amount of spaces indented on the first line, not blindly all whitespace in the beginning of each line. And your implementation does exactly that!

Comment: Could you please double-check and give me a couple of examples? It is supposed to look for the margin in the second and next lines. I'll try to add doctests today.

Comment: @kjellander I added the doctests. Please let me know if you have a concrete input that doesn't produce the result as expected.